# if block scoped type not reflecting through generics

Tags: typescript

```
class Foo {
  asdf: string;
}

class Bar {
  qwerty: number;
}

export type EntityTypeName = 'Foo' | 'Bar';

export type EntityType = Foo | Bar;

export type EntityTypeByName<N> =
  N extends 'Foo' ? Foo :
  N extends 'Bar' ? Bar :
  any;

class Wrapper <N extends EntityTypeName = EntityTypeName, T extends EntityType = EntityTypeByName<N>> {
  entityTypeName: N;
  entity: T;
}

const wrapper1 = new Wrapper<'Foo'>();

  wrapper1.entityTypeName; // "Foo"
  wrapper1.entity; // Foo

const wrapper2 = new Wrapper();

if (wrapper2.entityTypeName === 'Foo') {
  wrapper2.entityTypeName; // "Foo"
  wrapper2.entity; // Foo | Bar (expect Foo)
}
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sqd5uf

I hoped line 39 would show type `Foo` on mouse over because it is in the if block starting on line 37 and because generic `T` on line 25 being `EntityTypeByName<N>` defined line 20. Is there a way to accomplish line 39 showing type `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you want would be incorrect.  Since `wrapper2` is a `Wrapper<"Foo" | "Bar", Foo | Bar>`, it is valid for `wrapper2.entityTypeName` to be `"Foo"` but `wrapper2.entity` to be a `Bar`.  To capture the relationship between `entityTypeName` and `entity`, you need to use a discriminated union type:

```
type Wrapper<N extends EntityTypeName = EntityTypeName> =
  {[P in N]: {entityTypeName: P, entity: EntityTypeByName<P>}}[N];

let wrapper1: Wrapper<'Foo'>;

  wrapper1.entityTypeName; // "Foo"
  wrapper1.entity; // Foo

let wrapper2: Wrapper;

if (wrapper2.entityTypeName === 'Foo') {
  wrapper2.entityTypeName; // "Foo"
  wrapper2.entity; // Foo
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble, I need Wrapper to be a class, I tried https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bg844p

Comment: Your change has lost the relationship between `entityTypeName` and `entity` again, because `N` can be set to `"Foo" | "Bar"` and the types of `entityTypeName` and `entity` are generated independently based on `N`.  Why do you need `Wrapper` to be a class?  Maybe I can help you find another solution.